# Android: AdMob view disrupts input from gamepad (onKey events stop working)

Tags: android, admob, joystick, adview, gamepad

I’m displaying Admob banner ads in my game and I noticed that the AdView somehow messes up with the input from the gamepad.
For example buttons like X, A, L1, R1 stop working, they don't trigger `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` events. 
And other buttons generate incorrect key codes, for example when Y is pressed, instead of `KEYCODE_BUTTON_Y` I receive `KEYCODE_BUTTON_MENU`.

This problem happens after I touch the screen (not the banner itself). If I don't touch the screen, the gamepad works fine.

So it seems like AdView is 'stealing' key events, or something like that.

I experimented with different AdView settings like `setFocusable(false)`, position, tried assigning it custom KeyListener – nothing helps.
I tried 2 different gamepads and different android devices.
This problem disappears only when I remove the AdView or make it invisible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems like I found the solution. If I override `dispatchKeyEvent` and cancel dispatching onKey events to the AdView, then the gamepad works fine. Not sure if it's OK to do this, but it works.

```
public class MyAdView extends AdView {
    public MyAdView(Activity activity, AdSize adSize, String adUnitId) {
        super(activity, adSize, adUnitId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I love the solution but it is not possible to "subclass the final class AdView"

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me:**

```
    `// ADS
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(),  getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            RelativeLayout fl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameCounter);
            fl.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            fl.requestFocus();
        }
    });`
```

on the onAdLoaded event, I've set the focus to my layout and voile!!!